# Iterate through all Sites using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, hub-site

I am trying to disassociate all of my sites with my hub site and then associate them all again so that I can force an update of the styling. I know the code to remove an association and then create an association however I haven't been able to find any code to iterate through each site. There are no sub-sites and each site is found on https://.sharepoint.com/sites/ .

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can download the [SharePoint Online Management Shell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=35588).

And connect SharePoint online admin site and get the hub sites using the PowerShell below.

```
connect-SPOService -Url https://xxx-admin.sharepoint.com
Get-SPOHubSite
```

And get all the sites associated hub site base on the sub site Id.

```
$hubSiteId="9067810e-81f3-4798-a7b6-9d0b5daf25ce"
$sites = Get-SPOSite -Limit ALL 
foreach ($site in $sites) {
    $siteDetailed = Get-SPOSite -Detailed $site.Url
    if($siteDetailed.HubSiteId -eq $hubSiteId){
        $site.Url
    }
}
```